# Arranging Columns in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access to generate a report, but I'm encountering difficulty in figuring out how to have the information displayed in way that will comply to my preference. Specifically: the manner in which the data in my table is currently displayed is depicted below:

```
Day     Provider    Patient 
1/27    Johnson     Claire
1/27    Johnson     Tim
1/28    Johnson     Craig
1/27    Jane        Michael
1/28    Jane        Lisa
```

However, I would like the data to display as follows:

```
Provider    1/27    1/28
Johnson     2        1
Jane        1        1
```

My understanding of SQL is admittedly rudimentary, so I have been only able to come up with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT (Patient), Day, Provider
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Patient,Day, Provider FROM Records)
GROUP BY Day, Provider;
```

Is what I'm looking for possible in MS Access?

Comment: What you show is accomplished with a CROSSTAB query. Building stable CROSSTAB query to base a report on is tricky. Review http://www.access.hookom.net/DynamicMthlyCrosstabRpt.htm and https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/crosstab-report/index.html. Adapting for your daily output is even trickier but doable. Not showing year in date values. Is this data multi-year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using the Query Wizard in Access to create a Crosstab Query.

- Start by opening the wizard, and selecting "Crosstab Query Wizard" from the choices given when you start the wizard;
- Select the table required - I think that this is "Records" in your case;
- Select "Provider" as row header in the next screen;
- Select "Day" as the column header in the next screen;
- Select "Date" to group by in the next screen;
- Select "Count" as the value to be shown.

Your SQL should look like:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Records.[Patient]) AS CountOfPatient
SELECT Records.[Provider], Count(Records.[Patient]) AS [Total Of Patient]
FROM Records
GROUP BY Records.[Provider]
PIVOT Format([Day],"Short Date");
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to remember to keep this mind for other reports.